# CPTAnnotation.h not found

Tags: iphone, ipad

I recently switch to developer version 4.5 and found CPTAnnotation.h not found issue ,which was not there befor.
Any idea what i am missing.
This is related to coreplot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CPTAnnotation` is not part of the iOS SDK but the CorePlot library. Make sure you have added the library to your project ([here's how](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)) and imported the header file: `#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"`

Comment: i guess this is not an issue of coreplot, its an issue with migrating from xcode 4.3 to 4.5.